# The query results of Elasticsearch are less than the actual number of data when data in Elasticsearch update every 30s .

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use Grafana and display real time data in table. Grafana uses POST to obtain query results from Elasticsearch. While sometimes the number of acquired doc is less than the actual number. After several times refreshes the number of doc would be complete once while incomplete later. Why does it lack data in responses and not realize real time displaying. How can I obtain complete query results every 5s.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch is a Near Real Time solution ( take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html#_near_realtime_nrt) ). So your data in display in search after Lucene segment are merge into Lucene index.

This append where there is too many segment opended or the refresh interval of your elastic index kicks in.

To make it simple, you can configure the refresh interval of your index to obtain  a "more" real time behavior :

[Here is the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

```
PUT /<your_index>/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s"
    }
}
```

Will make your index change visible to search every second ( check the description [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings))

Comment: Though 1s is the default setting in Elasticsearch; so unless you have changed it this setting will not do anything for you.